# How to use getrusage for reading page errors in C?

Tags: c, getrusage

I'm trying to get the page faults when I run a program with two different parts.

What I do is some operations using two matrix multiplication methods and try to figure out wich one causes more page faults.

```
/Operations for method 1

getrusage (RUSAGE_SELF, &usage);
fault1=usage.ru_minflt;

/operations for Method 2


getrusage (RUSAGE_SELF, &usage);
fault2=usage.ru_minflt-fault1;
```

But seems that fault2=0, what I don't think is correct. If I use two different variables usage and usage2, seems not working neither.
Is there any command to start counting the faults for each multiplication method?
Am I wrong with the code?

Thanks for the answers

Answer (score 0):

It's entirely possible that the number of page faults *is* zero.  It's got more to do with the way in which you're loading data, which shared libraries you're using (and whether they're already in memory or not), copy-on-write usage and similar than it does with your algorithms.

Are you sure you're not looking for the number of processor cache misses instead? For matrix multiplication of large matrices, a naive algorithm can have much worse cache usage than an optimal one.  Try using `valgrind` with the `cachegrind` tool.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, how can I check the cache faults instead?

Comment: Run it under `cachegrind` (cache hits & misses occur deep in the hardware, below the level of the OS, so the OS doesn't keep track of them).